# How do I get a reference to UI elements in a storyboard view from the view's controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

I have a button and two text fields on the login screen of an app I'm writing.

[image: UI Situation]

When I use the "Go" button on my popup keyboard (or hit enter - it's in the simulator) I have a reference to the UITextField and use it to authenticate my users. It hits this method:

```
- (IBAction)getPassword:(UITextField *)sender {
[self setPassField:sender];
```

}

When I use the "Login" button, I am not getting a reference to the password text field and authentication fails every time (empty string is not the password).

Is there a way to get a handle on my fields from my view controller so I do not have to rely  on field-driven events to get field references?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update label/textfield of storyboard uiviewcontroller from controller.m?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393231/how-to-update-label-textfield-of-storyboard-uiviewcontroller-from-controller-m)

Comment: Long story short: Make an IBOutlet for your text fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two outlets in your view controller: one for the username text field and one for the password text field.  You need to connect the outlets to the fields in your storyboard.

Read [“Create Outlets for the Text Field and the Label” in *Your First iOS App*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH7-SW15) for Apple's step-by-step instructions on creating and connecting outlets.

Comment: I made the backing fields for both the user and password fields IBOutlet in my controller.h file and that solved the problem.